# Android : Managing two buttons

Tags: android, button, onclick

I have a problem concerning setting a listener that would execute different action based on the clicked button.

The compiler doesn't detect any error on the syntax, but the problem is that when I simulate my app on the emulator, it pops up the window asking for "Force Close".

Here is my Java file :

```
package tp.imc.namespace;



import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class IMCCalculatorActivity extends Activity {
   EditText poids,taille;
   Button boutton1,boutton2;
   TextView text1;
   Boolean k=true;
@Override

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
         super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
         setContentView(R.layout.main);
    poids=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.poids);
    taille=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.taille);
    boutton1 =(Button) findViewById(R.id.boutton1);
    text1=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.text1);
    boutton1.setOnClickListener(clicker);
    boutton2.setOnClickListener(clicker);
}

// declare a OnClickListener that will execute different actions
// depending on the view that was clicked
View.OnClickListener clicker = new View.OnClickListener(){
    public void  onClick  (View  v){
        if( v == boutton1 )
{
            String a,b;
    Double r;
    a=poids.getText().toString();
    b=taille.getText().toString();
    Double zero=Double.parseDouble(b);

    a=poids.getText().toString();
    b=taille.getText().toString();

    if (zero==0)
     {
    text1.setText("Erreur ! Division par 0.");

     }
    else {
        r=(Double.parseDouble(a))/(Double.parseDouble(b)*Double.parseDouble(b));
        if (r<16.5) text1.setText("Famine.");
        else if (r>16.5 && r<18.5) text1.setText("Maigreur.");
        else if (r>=18.5 && r<25) text1.setText("Coplulence nomrale.");
        else if (r>=25 && r<30) text1.setText("Surpoids.");
        else if (r>=30 && r<35) text1.setText("Obésité modérée.");
        else if (r>=35 && r<40) text1.setText("Obésité sévère.");
        else if (r>=40) text1.setText("Obésité morbide ou massive.");

         }

}           
        else if( v == boutton2 )

        {
             poids.setText("");
     taille.setText("");
     text1.setText("");
        }                          
}
 };
}
```

And here is my XML file :

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
    android:orientation="vertical">


<TextView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:text="@string/poids"
    android:textColor="#FF0000"
    android:gravity="center"

    />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/poids"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="@string/poids"
    android:lines="1"
    />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:text="@string/taille"
    android:textColor="#FF0000"
    android:gravity="center"
   />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/taille"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="@string/taille"
    android:lines="1" 
     />

<RadioGroup
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >
<RadioButton
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"  
    android:checked="true" 
    android:text="@string/metre"
    />
<RadioButton
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/centimetre"
     />

</RadioGroup>

<CheckBox 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/mega"
    android:checked="false"

    />


<Button
    android:id="@+id/boutton1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:text="@string/compute" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/boutton2"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/raz" />
<TextView 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:text="@string/resultat"
    />
<TextView  
    android:id="@+id/text1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:text="@string/text"
    />
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't define `boutton2`, it is null. Add this:

```
boutton2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.boutton2);
boutton2.setOnClickListener(clicker);
```

Since `boutton1` and `boutton2` don't have common code between them you could simply create two different listeners.

Lastly, this line doesn't look right.

```
if( v == boutton1 )
```

You are trying to compare a View to a Button which may not work. Try this:

```
if( v.getId() == boutton1.getId() )
```

Comment: Sam is right, also be sure to read Logcat when these problems occur, as it would have lead you to the line number causing the NullException.